# Loading time of php and getScript vary

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I found this oddity in my jquery-file while I was testing out some things on the localhost.
I've made a dropdownmenu which shows up one hidden div with php-content. I also added hyperlinks in each seperate php-file to navigate through the pages. Because it all has to display in one div, I wrote this script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.grouptwo').hide();
    $('#2013-2014').show();
    $.getScript("/localhost/Scripts/browsing.js");
    $('#ddmenu').change(function () {
        $('#browsing').html('');
        $('.grouptwo').hide();
        $('#'+$(this).val()).fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

And the browsing.js file looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('a.browselink').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#browsing').load($(this).attr("href"));
    $('.grouptwo').hide();
    $.getScript("/localhost/Scripts/browsing.js");
    });
});
```

This script should make sure on every new loaded page, the script is functioning.

However, when I tried clicking trough it, I found out that most of the time the script is included **after** the php, as it should, but sometimes (especially when you're clicking really fast) it gets the script **before** the php is loaded. I screenshotted the Google Chrome console to show what I mean [here](http://oi40.tinypic.com/29ler00.jpg).

This is annoying because the script won't work if it's loaded before the php-file. I've tried to find a regularity in when this exactly happens, but it seems quite random. Does anyone have an idea why this happens and how to solve this? I could of course include the browsing.js file in every seperate PHP-file, but I wonder whether there are better solutions.

Comment: you don't need to keep reloading your script the `on` function binds to newly added elements

Comment: I've tried that, but it only works once. When you click through twice, it doesn't load the script anymore. It seems to me like it has something to do with the hidden div's?

Comment: change it to `$('body').on('click', 'a.browselink', function(e){`